# How to fix sync problem with laravel livewire?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I've two tables orders & products and join table (order_product)
after creating or updating order through this code

```
        $order = Order::with([
            'address' => fn ($q) => $q->with('governorate', 'city'),
            'user',
            'products' => fn ($q) => $q->select('products.id', 'products.quantity', 'product_id'),
        ])->updateOrCreate(
            [
                'user_id'       =>  auth()->user()->id,
                'status_id'     =>  1
            ],
            [
                'num_of_items'      =>      Cart::instance('cart')->count(),
                'zone_id'           =>      $array_data['zone_id'],
                'coupon_id'         =>      $array_data['coupon_id'],
                'subtotal_base'     =>      $array_data['subtotal_base'],
                'subtotal_final'    =>      $array_data['subtotal_final'] - $this->points_egp - $this->balance,
                'delivery_fees'     =>      $array_data['delivery_fees'],
                'used_points'       =>      $this->points ?? 0,
                'gift_points'       =>      $array_data['gift_points'] ?? 0,
                'used_balance'      =>      $this->balance ?? 0,
                'total_weight'      =>      $array_data['weight'],
                'payment_method'    =>      $this->payment_method,
                'payment_status'    =>      0,
                'status_id'         =>      $this->payment_method == 4 ? 2 : 1,
            ]
        );
```

then I sync the products in the cart with the order just created through this block of code

```
        // get order's products
        $products = Cart::instance('cart')->content()->keyBy("id")->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                'quantity' => $item->qty
            ];
        })->toArray();

// update order's products
        $order->products()->sync(
            $products
        );
```

The problem is: that when I click the submit button (in livewire comp.) and `dd($order->product)` the first time gives an empty array but when I click on it the second time it works properly

Comment: Have you checked if the relation is refreshed after your `sync`? The database might be updated, but if your order still has the 'old' situation eager loaded, then you won't be seeing the just synced products. Perhaps a `$order->load('products')` after the `sync` will do the trick

Comment: You are right, this is the problem :) :)